# Error while installing squid on ubuntu

Tags: apt, xubuntu

```
 dpkg: error processing package squid3 (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit      status 102
 /bin/df: no file systems processed
                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.15-    0ubuntu10.15) ...
    ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 squid3
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to fix this errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have found 2 things about this line:

> /bin/df: no file systems processed

You can either be out of space:

http://it.i88.ca/2012/12/df-shows-no-file-systems-processed.html

or, in case you are using OpenVZ:

https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/df-shows-no-file-systems-processed/

Now, once you have corrected that issue attempt to reinstall the package again.